# Can we get a virus by allowing an External Protocol Request in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, bittorrent

When opening torrents, I would always download the .torrent file and manually open them using uTorrent.

There's an alternative way called the [magnet links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme). How safe are magnet links compared to manually opening .torrent files?

[image]

What are the chances of getting a virus just by clicking <kbd>Launch Application</kbd>?

Comment: Don't think so. I think it is referring to the torrent its self, which like to have viruses.. I believe that the downloading of the torrent is what it is considering a potential attack

Comment: @ekaj I mean assuming the torrented file itself is clean, is launching it through a magnet link a potential attack zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its about as safe as launching any other third party application to run an arbitrary file.

Lets say you go to www.dodgysite.notreal, and you get a popup asking you to run a external application *without* prompting, hit do nothing, and run like hell. The worst case scenario here is you end up launching an application with a known vulnerability, and your system is compromised through that.

On the other hand, this will happen if you launch *any* filetype not handled by chrome or explicitly stated as being safe. Its just a sanity check type warning not to run random crap. As such, as long as you're actually clicking and running a magnet link, from a reasonably trustworthy site, you should be safe.

Comment: The image does shows the link requested (magnet:?xt=urn:), I was wondering is it possible that there is *something else* linked instead of a torrent file?

Comment: Its about the same. If its a non magnet file link thats opened, your torrent client will just barf on it, and refuse to have anything to do with it, really

Comment: how do we tell if it is targeting *another* app besides the expected uTorrent magnet links? (For example, I wouldn't want to allow it to run any other app besides the one linked to .torrent)

Answer (score 0):

I got brave (or stupid?) and launched the application and checked "remember my choice". Utorrent opened, I loaded the torrent and all was fine.

Comment: thanks for your first answer! Just a tip though: While past experience is great, always try to answer the question directly as possible when using an answer. I'd recommend using a comment for such past experiences.

Comment: @bic, Ok... but if there was a virus it is not going to be so easily seen...